# Unexplained gap in SSRS report Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, visual-studio-2019, ssrs-tablix

Edit:  This space is appearing only when the report is exported to Word (from Dynamics CRM), if exported to PDF, the spacing is fine, but the fonts aren't visible.  I believe this is a limitation of dynamics crm reports to pdf- that the fonts can't be embedded.

I have a report that is creating a strange gap between particular rows.  I've reduced the padding, and made the space before and space after 0pt, but I can't adjust this gap. It seems to be a problem with the Trademark name box, and this is what is really problematic for my report, but there is also an unexplained gap after new_general as well - perhaps there is an overall setting between rows that needs to be adjusted?  I would appreciate some solutions.  Thank you!

[image]

This is from the report design - is there something else I should be checking?
[image]

[image]

Comment: You should also check `.CanGrow` and `.CanShrink` properties of Tablix row. Maybe you `[new_general]` field contains one or more `NewLine` before or after text?

Comment: @tezzo , i double checked that now.  CanGrow and CanShrink are set to false, and it's still happening.  You helped me realize though that this is only happening on export to word, when I export to PDF there isn't any issue.  Unfortunately I can't get the fonts to display properly in PDF.  I will edit my question.